# Removing duplicates from a sorted list c#

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

I have a list of details about a large number of files. This list contains the file ID, last modified date and the file path. The problem is there are duplicates of the files which are older versions and sometimes have different file paths. I want to only store the newest version of a file regardless of file path. So I created a loop that iterates through the ordered list, checks to see if the ID is unique and if it is, it gets stored in a new unique list.

```
 var ordered = list.OrderBy(x => x.ID).ThenByDescending(x => x.LastModifiedDate);

            List<Item> unique = new List<Item>();

            string curAssetId = null;

            foreach (Item result in ordered)
            {
                if (!result.ID.Equals(curAssetId))
                {
                    unique.Add(result);
                    curAssetId = result.ID;
                }
            }
```

However this is still allowing duplicates into the DB and I can't figure out why this code isn't working as expected. By duplicates I mean, the files have the same ID but different file paths, which like I said before shouldn't be an issue. I just want the latest version regardless of pathway. Can anyone else see what the issue is? Thanks

```
   var ordered = listOfItems.OrderBy(x => x.AssetID).ThenByDescending(x => x.LastModifiedDate);
            List<Item> uniqueItems = new List<Item>();

            foreach (Item result in ordered)
            {
                if (!uniqueItems.Any(x => x.AssetID.Equals(result.AssetID)))
                {
                    uniqueItems.Add(result);

                }
            }
```

this is what I have now and it is still allowing duplicates

Comment: what is the exact value of your `LastModifiedDate`? this `date` has a `hour:mm:ss`?

Comment: yes that is the format

Comment: try to get the exact date value with no `hour:mm:ss` and use the `.Distinct`. can you try my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because , you are not searching entire list to check whether the id is unique or not

```
List<Item> unique = new List<Item>();

        string curAssetId = null; // here is the problem 

        foreach (Item result in ordered)
        {
            if (!result.ID.Equals(curAssetId)) // here you only compare the last value.
            {
                unique.Add(result);
                curAssetId = result.ID; // You are only assign the current ID value and 
            }
        }
```

to solve this , change the following

```
     if (!result.ID.Equals(curAssetId)) // here you only compare the last value.
        {
            unique.Add(result);
            curAssetId = result.ID; // You are only assign the current ID value and 
        }
```

to

```
if (!unique.Any(x=>x.ID.Equals(result.ID))) 
        {
            unique.Add(result);

        }
```

Comment: this method still allows the duplicates for some reason. Can you think of anything else I could still be missing? thanks

Comment: i don't believe it , just amended some of the portion of the answer

Comment: I added what I now have in my program up above and it is still allowing duplicates. It is very strange

Comment: there is something else happening , i am sure above corrections for duplicate ID will work, it just check if there is any item with the current ID in the unique list.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After some investigation I realised there was a problem with the way my multithreading was adding to the list so I changed that and it seems to be working now!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this code is just simplified, but have you considered grouping on ID, sorting on LastModifiedDate, then just taking the first from each group?

Something like:

```
var unique = list.GroupBy(i => i.ID).Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.LastModifiedDate).First());
```

Comment: I tried this method and it still saves duplicates. It doesn't seem to make sense how its still happening

Comment: Are you sure your list has the full set of items? You will get duplicate IDs if you are not working with everything.

Comment: This answer was perfect for a problem I had where I wanted to group records by an ID, then sort within each group and only get the first record from each group, and all into a single enumerable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`var ordered = list.OrderBy(x => x.ID).ThenByDescending(x => x.LastModifiedDate).Distinct()` ??

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you have to create your own EquityComparer and after that you could use linq's Distinct method. [Enumerable.Distinct at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx)

Also I think you could stay with your current code but you have to modify it in such a way (as a sample):

```
    var ordered = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastModifiedDate);
    var unique = new List<Item>();

    foreach (Item result in ordered)
    {
        if (unique.Any(x => x.ID == result.ID))
            continue;
        unique.Add(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Item> p = new List<Item>();
var x = p.Select(c => new Item
     {
         AssetID = c.AssetID,
         LastModifiedDate = c.LastModifiedDate.Date
     }).OrderBy(y => y.id).ThenByDescending(c => c.LastModifiedDate).Distinct();
```

Comment: The problem is I need the time in the date because it was a requirement of the program. I tried the answer anyway, but now no records are being returned.

Comment: use the `.ToList()` place after the `.Distinct()`. looks like `.Distinct().ToList();`